# Can't Call function in another class due to initialiser

Tags: ios, swift, function, initialization, nscoder

I am trying to call a function from TheTimer class from my MainClass class. However, in the TheTimer class there is a required init, and when I try and call the Start function from the TheTimer class (I call it from the MainClass class) it throws the error: Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call

The TheTimer class is responsible for a UIView that is part of my storyboard.

TheTimer:

```
class TheTimer: UIView {

var timeLabel: UILabel

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

 timeLabel = UILabel()
 super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 let viewWidth = self.frame.size.width
 let viewHeight = self.frame.size.height
 timeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
 timeLabel.text = "0"
 timeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 45)
 timeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
 self.addSubview(timeLabel)
 }

//MARK: Properties
var time: Double = 0.000

var timer = Timer()

func Start() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: #selector(countUp), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func countUp() {
    time += 0.001


}
```

MainClass Class

```
import UIKit

class MainClass: UIViewController {
//MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!


//MARK: Go

@IBAction func startAll(_ sender: UIButton) {
    TheTimer().Start() //Throws error 'Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call'

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainClass` class, create a property for your `TheTimer` view, after that connect your `TheTimer` in story board with this `IBOutlet`. Finally, call `theTimer.Start()` instead of `TheTimer().Start()`

```
import UIKit

class MainClass: UIViewController {
//MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var theTimer: TheTimer!


//MARK: Go

@IBAction func startAll(_ sender: UIButton) {
    theTimer.Start() // It will work fine

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre calling an empty init() function, which you have not written. Your only init is the required init and you dont match its parameters. I would suggest writing a second init function with all of your initialization stuff in it.

```
init() {

 timeLabel = UILabel()
 super.init()
 let viewWidth = self.frame.size.width
 let viewHeight = self.frame.size.height
 timeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
 timeLabel.text = "0"
 timeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 45)
 timeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
 self.addSubview(timeLabel)
 }
```

and then

```
 TheTimer().Start()
```

Comment: This will not compile, it is a subclass of UIView, so it has to call init(frame: CGRect)

Comment: @rmaddy for me it does not compile. Keeps saying you need to call designated initializer of the superclass UIView. If you know something I do not know, I will be happy to learn. And the other problem is the time label not being initialized at the super.init.

Comment: I am not really sure about the init(frame), but you should be right with the timelabel not being initialized. I edited my post, initializing the timelabel before calling the super.init

Comment: you are not allowed to call `super.init()`. Superclass convenience initializer can never be called directly by a subclass

Answer (score 0):

Yasin was correct, you will have to create the other init. Plus you might separate the code into a separate method. I do not understand though why do you need it to be a UIView and have a label if you do not use any of these.

```
init() {
    timeLabel = UILabel()
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    timeLabel = UILabel()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

func setupView() {
    let viewWidth = self.frame.size.width
    let viewHeight = self.frame.size.height
    timeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
    timeLabel.text = "0"
    timeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 45)
    timeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    self.addSubview(timeLabel)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've provided the required initializer `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, so the default `convenience initializer` has gone. So there is no `init()` for TheTimer() class. Your error happened at TheTimer() not Start().

There are two methods to go:

**1.** Call initialization code in `awakeFromNib()` instead of `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.
`awakeFromNib()`will be called right after the view been loaded from an Interface Builder archive, or nib.
Then you should change the `var timeLabel: UILabel` to `var timeLabel: UILabel! or ?` since you didn't initialize it in an initializer.
**2.** Write an initializer yourself

```
init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero) // you need to give it a frame, right?

        // Your initialization code
        timeLabel = UILabel()
        let viewWidth = self.frame.size.width
        let viewHeight = self.frame.size.height
        timeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
        timeLabel.text = "0"
        timeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 45)
        timeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.addSubview(timeLabel)
    }
```

BTW, you should name a function with lowercase.
[The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4): Initialization
developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)